# Delphi Indy HTTPS web server errors (EOF was observed that violates the protocol)

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy, indy10

I am trying to add HTTPS support to an existing web server written in Delphi XE7 using Indy. I have written a simple application which just returns a date/time stamp on each HTTPS request.

I added handlers to the `OnCommandGet` and `OnException` events:

```
procedure TForm13.HTTPServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  AResponseInfo.ContentText := DateTimeToStr(Now());
  AResponseInfo.ContentEncoding := 'utf8';

  Log('Request: %s', [ARequestInfo.URI]);
end;

procedure TForm13.HTTPServerException(AContext: TIdContext; AException: Exception);
begin
  Log('Exception raised %s:%s', [AException.ClassName, AException.Message]);
end;
```

Bindings code:

```
  with HTTPServer do
   begin
     with Bindings.Add() do
      begin
        IP := '0.0.0.0';
        Port := 443;
      end;

     Active := true;
   end;
```

When I perfrom a request from a browser, in most cases I get this:

```
12.03.2019 0:50:29  Exception raised EIdConnClosedGracefully:Connection Closed Gracefully.
12.03.2019 0:50:29  Exception raised EIdConnClosedGracefully:Connection Closed Gracefully.
12.03.2019 0:50:30  Request: /
12.03.2019 0:50:30  Exception raised EIdConnClosedGracefully:Connection Closed Gracefully.
12.03.2019 0:50:30  Request: /favicon.ico
12.03.2019 0:51:00  Exception raised EIdSocketError:Socket Error # 10060    Connection timed out.
```

It serves the request and the browser shows the timestamp. But why does a graceful connection close raise an exception?

What bothers me more is that sometimes after 30 seconds after the last request, I get another exception, like this:

```
12.03.2019 1:44:53  Exception raised EIdConnClosedGracefully:Connection Closed Gracefully.
12.03.2019 1:44:53  Exception raised EIdConnClosedGracefully:Connection Closed Gracefully.
12.03.2019 1:44:53  Request: /
12.03.2019 1:44:54  Exception raised EIdConnClosedGracefully:Connection Closed Gracefully.
12.03.2019 1:44:54  Request: /favicon.ico
12.03.2019 1:45:24  Exception raised EIdOSSLAcceptError:Error accepting connection with SSL. EOF was observed that violates the protocol
```

It happens randomly, sometimes it is a timeout, sometimes this one. This looks wrong for me. Any ideas why this happens?

PS: In Delphi 10.3 it happens the same way as in Delphi XE7, so probably all Indy versions are affected.

Comment: On a side note, `utf8` is not a valid value for the `AResponseInfo.ContentEncoding` property. If you want the text to be UTF-8 encoded, you need to set the `AResponseInfo.CharSet` property instead.

Comment: You did not show the code that sets up the server's `Bindings` collection. Are you making the server listen on port 80 or 443? Do you have an `OnQuerySSLPort` event handler assigned? The symptoms you describe are caused by the client disconnecting on its end. The `EIdConnClosedGracefully` is perfectly normal, just ignore it. It means the client disconnected in between requests. The EOF error means the client disconnected in the middle of the SSL/TLS handshake.

Comment: I have added bindings code to the post, but I am sure there is nothing special in it. I also tryed to add OnQuerySSLPort (always returning true), it does not change anything.

Comment: how exactly have your configured the `SSLIOHandler` that you have assigned to the server?

Comment: I have tried different variants in SSLOptions: 
Mode: sslmServer or sslmUnassigned, SSLVersions: different sets,
CertFile, KeyFile and RootCertFile are all assigned to a same file with self-created certificate.

Comment: Then I suggest you use a packet sniffer like Wireshark to look at the actual SSL/TLS handshake and see at what stage the browser is disconnecting. There is probably something in your handshake that the browser doesn't like. For example, if you use a self-signed certificate, did you install it in your browser beforehand?  Browsers don't generally like self-signed certificates without user approval.

Comment: Try to update you SSL dlls to the latest verison..

Answer (score 0):

Finally found that all this strange errors appear only in case of self-generated certificate which is not installed on client device.